# Display Post Titles on top of the_post_thumbnail()

Tags: php, images

I'm working on an issue that's just about solved, but I'm currently stuck. I've changed content php to change the way posts are displayed. I've ran $wp_query->current_post to determine what the post count is, and styled each one individually.

The first post (post count 0) has a bigger featured image and headline. The 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th posts have no excerpt – only a featured image, 250x250, in a group of four (like the boxes on this site: http://roispark.com)

I have this all working, however, I need to be able to put the post titles on top of these images. Since content.php generates each image by itself, 4 times, I can't use relative/absolute positioning, or all the titles are stacked on top of each other.

Here's my code:

```
<header>
<?php if ( $wp_query->current_post == 0 && !is_paged() ) { ?>
  <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
  <?php get_template_part('templates/entry-meta'); ?>
  <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail('homepage-first-thumb');
    } ?>

<?php } elseif ( $wp_query->current_post == 1 
|| $wp_query->current_post == 2 
|| $wp_query->current_post == 3 
|| $wp_query->current_post == 4 
&& !is_paged() ) { ?>  

<div class="post-boxes">
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('homepage-thumb'); ?></a>
</div>

<?php } else { ?>
  <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail('homepage-child');
  } ?>
  <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
  <?php get_template_part('templates/entry-meta'); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Any ideas on how I can get the_title to show up on the images?

**EDIT:**

Here's the LESS I have associated with the post-box:

```
.post-boxes {
    position: relative;
    img {
        margin-right: 35px;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
    p {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
    }
}
```

It seems like it should be displaying correctly. However, here's an image of what it's doing on my site:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbRvE.jpg

Comment: Looks like you're having a CSS issue and not a WP issue. Absolute positioning is positioned according to it's parent. As long as the parent position is defined. So if all your titles are stacked upon each each other and yet each title has it's own div box, you need to set the div box with position:relative. And the title itself with position:absolute. This way the title will be positioned in relation to it's parent (the div) and not the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant 'top: -50;', as a negative number brings up and a positive number brings down your paragraph.

Comment: The issue is that each title of the post is stacked one on top of the other. I can change it to -50, but then they all move up. I want to separate them and basically "attach" them to the image they're associated with.